# Add UIView in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am using ScrollView instead of UICollectionView for showing image. After three images the fourth image will be placed in below the first Like
**1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9**
Please any one share the logic of this.

```
self.dataArr = [@[@"1", @"1", @"1", @"2", @"2", @"1", @"2", @"3", @"1", @"2", @"4", @"5", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"1", @"6", @"7"]mutableCopy]; 
   int x = 5; int y = 5; 
 for (int i = 0; i< self.dataArr.count; i++) {
   UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 100, 100)];
   view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]; 
   [contentSv addSubview:view]; 
   x += 105; 
   y = ? contentSv.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, y); 
   }
```

Comment: Have you done anything so far? What does your scrollView code look like? How are you creating images?

Comment: After three images the fourth image will be placed in below the first

Comment: You question really looks like a code request, please show that you have tried to solve this issue yourself and not just want code. Most people here are making a living writing code and will therefor not just give you code.

Comment: self.dataArr = [@[@"1", @"1", @"1", @"2", @"2", @"1", @"2", @"3", @"1", @"2", @"4", @"5", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"1", @"6", @"7"]mutableCopy];
    
    int x = 5;
    
    int y = 5;
    
    for (int i = 0; i< self.dataArr.count; i++)
    {
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 100, 100)];
        
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        
        [contentSv addSubview:view];
        
        x += 105;
        
        y = ?
        contentSv.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, y);
     }

Comment: Please add your code to the original question.

Comment: In above code i am confused how to set the **y** position

Answer (score 0):

```
self.dataArr = [@[@"1", @"1", @"1", @"2", @"2", @"1", @"2", @"3", @"1", @"2", @"4", @"5", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"1", @"6", @"7"]mutableCopy]; 
   int x = 5; int y = 5; int count = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i< self.dataArr.count; i++) {
   count++;
   UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 100, 100)];
   view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]; 
   [contentSv addSubview:view]; 
   x += 105; 

   if (count == 4){
     count = 0;
     y+= 105;  //set your appropriate height here.
     x = 5;
   }

   //y = ? contentSv.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, y); 
   }
```

Hope this helps.